# const decltype(*std::begin(container))& val doesn't make val const?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lambda, constants, c++11

This piece of code:

```
std::vector <int> ints(5,1);
std::for_each(ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](const decltype(*std::begin(ints))& val){ val*=2; });
```

compiles and runs just fine in Visual Studio 2010, and modifies every value in the container like if the const keyword weren't there. Is this a bug in the compiler, as the expected behaviour is that val is non-modifiable? (in other words, I expect it not to compile, but it does)

*Update:*

```
std::for_each(ints.begin(), ints.end(), [](const std::remove_reference<decltype(*std::begin(ints))>::type& val){ val*=2; });
```

seems to behave const-correctly, however that doesn't make me smarter.

*Note:*

`decltype(*std::begin(ints))` is a reference to an int.

Comment: gcc just refuses to compile: `error: ‘const’ qualifiers cannot be applied to ‘int&’`.

Comment: it refuses to compile both versions?

Comment: Of course, the second does not compile because `val` is a constant which cannot be `*= 2`-ed.

Comment: Ah, yea stupid me =) thats whats its supposed to do, but the first one doesn't compile either in gcc?

Comment: Right, the first one errors with the message I shown in the first comment.

Comment: @KennyTM: g++ is perfectly happy to apply `const` to `int&`: http://ideone.com/KSno3 (C++03) http://ideone.com/aLTJO (C++11)

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, the `const` is ignored if the reference is introduced through `typedef` or template argument (§8.3.2/1). `decltype` isn't one of them.

Answer (score 8):

<strike>It seems the compiler tries to apply the `const` to the `int&`, making it `int& const`, which is superfluous as a reference can't be reseated anyways<sup>1)</sup>. Try putting the const between the `decltype` and the reference: `decltype(*ints.begin()) const&`</strike>

1) Thanks for the comments for the clarification.

Scrap that, thanks to @Ben's comment I noticed the real problem. Try `decltype(*ints.cbegin())`. `cbegin` returns a `const_iterator`, which dereferences to a reference-to-const. Also, no need for the extra ampersand, as `*ints.cbegin()` already returns a `int const&`.

To explain what went wrong in the OP's code, it's just as @Ben Voigt says in the comments: `decltype(*std::begin(ints))` resolves to `int&`, since `std::begin(ints)` returns a non-const iterator for non-const containers and dereferencing such an iterator returns a reference-to-non-const.

Comment: GCC should simply ignore the const, making the resulting type an `int&`.

Comment: @Johannes: Why? I expect the code to give me a compilation error.

Comment: Applying `const` to `int&` is perfectly legal: http://ideone.com/aLTJO (and Comeau accepts it also).

Comment: @Ben: Interesting, I'll amend my answer accordingly. Though, just because two compilers accept it doesn't mean it's legal per-se. I'll just believe you and Johannes though.

Comment: @Xeo: Your fix won't help.  The `declspec` part resolves to `int&`, already a reference.

Comment: @Ben: Ohh, I see the problem now. Got distracted by the `&` after it. Damn reference collapsing rules. :P Amending my answer again, this time with the hopefully correct fix. Alas, I have no compiler handy to test it though...

Comment: @ViktorSehr: Is there something still missing in my answer? If yes, please tell me. If not, I'd appreciate it if you would accept it. :)

Comment: @Xeo: I guess what was the answer to my question was "the const is ignored if the reference is introduced through typedef or template argument" as is said in the last comment to the question.